# Why my SP is taking too long time to excute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 15.0.2070.41, and I have Stored procedure like:
Here i am getting data as acpected but only the problem is its taking too ling time i.e. aprox 26 sec so due to this in frontend i am getting error like application time out check your internet connectivity. Please help me

```
 create PROC [dbo].[report_interface]  
 @reportID AS INT,  
 @startRow AS INT,  
 @numberOfRows AS INT,  
 @action AS VARCHAR(20) = 'SELECT',  
 @stock_type AS NVARCHAR(2) = NULL,  
 @sap_system AS NVARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
 @plant AS NVARCHAR(50) = NULL  
AS    
DECLARE @reportName VARCHAR(100)  
DECLARE @rowCount INT   
   SET @reportName = 'Interface'   
IF @numberOfRows = 0 OR @numberOfRows IS NULL  
BEGIN  
   SET @numberOfRows = 100000000
END    
   SET NOCOUNT ON  
IF @action = 'SELECT'  
BEGIN  
;WITH TempResult AS(  
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), s.date_loaded, 113) AS received  
      ,upload_stock_type AS stock_type  
      ,s.sap_system AS sap_system
       FROM i_hold_sap_stock s  
      ,(SELECT sap_system  
      ,max(date_loaded) date_loaded  
     FROM i_hold_sap_stock s 
     WHERE  ((s.conv_zgport_ship ='LKCMB' AND YEAR(conv_stock_date) >=2017 ) OR  (s.conv_zgport_ship !='LKCMB' AND YEAR(conv_stock_date)=YEAR(s.conv_stock_date) OR conv_stock_date IS NULL))   
     GROUP BY sap_system) sd  
     WHERE sd.sap_system = s.sap_system  
   AND sd.date_loaded = s.date_loaded  
   AND ((@stock_type IS NULL) OR (upload_stock_type = @stock_type))  
   AND ((@sap_system IS NULL) OR (s.sap_system LIKE '%' + @sap_system + '%'))
    ), TempCount AS (  
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS MaxRows FROM TempResult  
 )    
 SELECT * into #DTTempTable FROM TempResult TR, TempCount  
 ORDER BY stock_type,sap_system OFFSET @startRow ROWS FETCH NEXT @numberOfRows ROWS ONLY
 SELECT * FROM #DTTempTable  
 SELECT @rowCount = (SELECT TOP 1 MaxRows FROM #DTTempTable)  
 SELECT  
  @reportName AS ReportName,  
  @rowCount AS NumberOfRecords,  
  '[{"DONOTFORMATCOLUMNS": "upload_plant,batch_no,po_number"}]' as ReportAttributes    
END
```

Where i need to change or what can i do for executing in faster manner please help me

I follow these steps:

1. Avoid Local variable
2. Decrease Records size i.e. Top 1000

But Still no any changes

Comment: A brief look over. Things like `AND YEAR(conv_stock_date) >= 2017` will make the query non-SARGable, so indexes won't be able to be used (it should be `AND conv_stock_date >= '20170101'`). You also have a clause with a leading wild card (`s.sap_system LIKE '%' + @sap_system + '%'`) which can't be made SARGable at all.

Comment: You also have the clause `AND YEAR(conv_stock_date) = YEAR(s.conv_stock_date)`, which is completely pointless. The value of `conv_stock_date` is never going to not equal the value of `conv_stock_date`, unless they have the value `NULL` (`s` is the alias of the only table in the subquery, so both of those will reference the same column).

Comment: Larnu In this (s.sap_system LIKE '%' + @sap_system + '%')  what should i change??

Comment: You can't make a clause with a leading wildcard SARGable. And without knowing what the goal is, the value of `@sap_system` and the types of values that would be stored in `s.sap_system`, I have no way of knowing if a Full Text Index would help.

Comment: @sap_system it is optional if value is not getting from fronted then search text

Comment: "an optional value" doesn't tell me anything about what I mentioned above. You treat `@numberOfRows` like it's an "optional" parameter in the definition, but its not. Honestly, for us to be able to help you, we need to have the definition of the table, it's indexes, and then sample data. You'll need to explain your goals and provide expected results. Simply, as it is, the query above will be slow, as it *will* need to use Scans. As we don't know the goal, or what the data looks like, and you have leading wildcard, we have no way of knowing what the correct route to make it faster is.

Comment: First step is to format your code to make it readable and understandable. And if `@action <> 'SELECT'` your procedure does nothing? And `@reportname` is never really used except as a literal in a resultset. I see other parameters are never used. And i see a huge problem after attempting a reformat - you use old style joins which are prone to errors. Just **START OVER** and rewrite this from scratch using current best practices.